# Unity 5 Admob Google Play Service Issue - duplicated prettify.js

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am currently working on a Unity/Android Project. To integrate admob I followed this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/admob/games?hl=en#requirements

At some point the guide tells me to

> 1. The plugin requires the Google Play services library to be included in the project. Add the entire /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/ folder into the Assets/Plugins/Android folder of your Unity project.

Hence yesterday I upgraded to Google Play Services V.26 via the Android SDK Manager. And thereafter followed the instructions from the guide and copied

Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services

to

C:\Users\Me\MyGame\Assets\Plugins\Android

However when trying to build the Android project in Unity now, it will complain about duplicated js files such as prettify.js in the google_play_services that I copied over:

> Scripts named 'prettify.js" exists in multiple locations (Assets/Plugins/Android/google_play_services/docs/assets/js/prettify.js). Please rename one of the scripts to a unique name.

The reason is - that the original folder in Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services really does have duplicated js files! So it is not something that happens in unity or by copying it to unity. The following screenshot shows the duplicate js file:

[image]

I have no idea if I can just delete one of the scripts but I wouldn't know which one... Though I'd be inclined to delete the one in \docs, not the one in docs\assets....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you coppied "android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services" into Plugins/Android ? This is the problem. You shouldn't. Just copy "android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services **\libproject\google-play-services_lib**" into plugins/android

Comment: Oh boy, I guess I should get a new pair of glasses - you're absolutely right !